# excel select last two columns and extend

Tags: excel, vba

I like to have a VBA code that selects the last two columns of my sheet.
When the columns are selected they need to be extended until column DI.

what i have so far as code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
'select the last two columns

    Range("G9").Select
    Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
    ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Resize(, 2).Offset(, -1).Select

'Extend the two last columns until it have reached column: DI

End Sub
```

Now i only need to add the code for draggin the two columns until it reached column "DI" as seen in the image below. i dont have the reputation for images so its became a link
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiISr.png)

any ideas?

Comment: Extended? What does that mean? What have you managed so far?

Comment: i added what i have.

Answer (score 0):

This will select the columns between your last column (based on data in row 9 as you used `G9`) and column `DI`.

```
Sub test()

    Dim rng As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(9, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).EntireColumn, .Columns("DI"))
    End With

    'Try not to select ranges before using them.
    MsgBox rng.Address
    rng.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) 'Turn background to yellow.

    rng.Select 'Select the range.

End Sub
```

The selection will include the last populate column.
So might want to use `.Cells(9, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1).EntireColumn` instead.

Also if last populated column is > `DI` it will select backwards so could select column `DN:DI` for example.

**Edit:**
To autofill from last populated column to column `DI`:

```
Sub test()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rngStart As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set rngStart = .Cells(9, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, -1).EntireColumn.Resize(, 2)
        Set rng = .Range(rngStart, .Columns("DI"))
    End With

    rngStart.AutoFill rng, xlFillValues

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks this selection works good. But it always selects until Column DI and i only want to select until the last two used columns, what do i have to change to make that happen?

Comment: I've updated the code so `rngStart` references the last two columns which are then autofilled across to `DI`.

Comment: the code works but it always selects until column "DI" and it needs to select only the last 2 columns and then autofill it from those last two culomns

Comment: You asked _I like to have a VBA code that selects the last two columns of my sheet. When the columns are selected they need to be extended until column DI._    Where does it autofill to if not column `DI`?

Comment: yes sorry, i meant something else. I mean it does not use the two columns that are selected (the last two). in each column is an function that adds +7 to a certain row. as seen in the picture. When i use the code it adds 1 and not 7. so that means it does not use the last two rows but only the last row.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the help i edited the code a bit to make it work for me.

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
Dim rng As Range
Dim rngStart As Range
Dim rngEnd As Range
Dim rngX As Range

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Blad1")
    Set rngStart = .Cells(9, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, -1).EntireColumn
    Set rngEnd = .Cells(9, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).EntireColumn
    Set rng = .Range(rngStart, .Columns("DI"))
    Set rngX = .Range(rngStart, rngEnd)

End With
rngX.AutoFill rng, xlFillDefault
```

Comment: That does exactly what my second block of code does.  Are you a manager by any chance? :)